# Bahs - How To Copy Files From A Directory To Multiple Directories?

Tags: bash, cp

The directory (mydir) has 1000 files (**ls | wc -l**) but I want to copy only those files with **file.num.txt** to a directory **num**.

Here is an example:

1. mydir

   - file.1
   - file.1.txt
   - file.2
   - file.2.txt
   - **...**
2. /home/user1/store dir has dirs like

   - dir1
   - dir2
   - **...**

So I want to copy **file.1.txt** to **dir1**, **file.2.txt** in **dir2** and so forth.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you attempted this yet? You need a loop over a glob and some basic shell variable expansions (or usage of `cut`/`awk`/etc.) to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
src="mydir"
dest="/home/user1/store"
dir="dir" #name of the dir without number, i.e dir from dir1, dir2
regex='(.*\.)([0-9]+)(\.txt$)'
for file in "$src"/*;do
  if [[ -f $file ]];then
    if [[ $file =~ $regex ]];then
      mkdir -p "$dest"/"$dir${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
      cp "$file" "$dest"/"$dir${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Explanation:

`${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` contains the captured group #2 (which is the number part of filename) from `$file` matched against pattern `$regex`. The pattern matching is done in the if statement:

```
if [[ $file =~ $regex ]];then
```

`mkdir -p` is used in case the directory structure doesn't exist, it will create it.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about mkdir -p, but you already explained, in my case that is not necessary and thank you so much. It works like a charm now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you can run:

```
parallel '{= $_ = /\.\d+\.txt$/ ? "true" : "false" =} && mkdir -p dir{= s/\D//g =} && cp {} dir{= s/\D//g =}' ::: file.*.txt
```

The first part evaluates to 'true' or 'false' and is a way of doing 'grep'. If you know 'file.*.txt' are all of the form 'file.num.txt' then it is not needed.

'mkdir -p' will create the dir if it is not already there.

The &&'s are needed to make sure the command is only run if the first part evaluates to 'true'.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: parallel seems a promise to the future; which I don't have access to on my system at the moment. I should look at the links to gets a heads up. Thank you.

Comment: `parallel` is great, but copying files is purely I/O bound.  Increasing parallelism in this particular case will only slow things down.

Comment: @lcd047 While that used to be true, it no longer is: I have used a RAID that was 6 times faster if I ran 10 jobs in parallel. The RAID was slower if I ran fewer or more jobs in parallel. With SSD disks it is even less true. So the only advice that really still holds is: measure which works better for you, and adjust with --jobs accordingly.

Comment: Even with a RAID, what `parallel` does is inappropriate, since it uses the number of CPU cores to set the number of jobs to run in parallel.  The number of CPU cores is completely irrelevant to I/O.  Also, I somehow suspect the vast majority of people reading this won't have a RAID 10, or a SAN connected through fiberchannel.

Comment: @lcd047 ... which is why you adjust with --jobs as mentioned. I am not sure why you bring up RAID 10 and SAN. My observations about speed is true for quite a number of scenarios: SSD, any RAID, and network file systems just to list three.  The only advice that really still holds is: measure which works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

i was wondering if this could be achieved with `find`'s -exec parameter or `xargs` but i got stuck on variable substitution for the filenames.

so i ended up on piping to bash's while

```
find mydir/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex ".*\.[0-9]+\(\|\.txt\)" | \
  while read line; do num=${line%\.txt}; \
   cp ${line} /home/user1/store/dir${num##*\.}; \
done
```